# React js change child component's state from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components:
**Parent Component** from which I want to change child component's state:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  toggleChildMenu() {
    ?????????
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={toggleChildMenu.bind(this)}>
          Toggle Menu from Parent
        </button>
        <ChildComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And **Child Component**:

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false;
    }
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer open={this.state.open}/>
    );
  }
}
```

I need to either change Child Component's **open** state from Parent Component, or call Child Component's **toggleMenu()** from Parent Component when Button in Parent Component is clicked?

Comment: Maybe you can hold a  child reference in parent, and change child's state explicitly,See this [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The state should be managed in the parent component. You can transfer the `open` value to the child component by adding a property.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        open: false
      };

      this.toggleChildMenu = this.toggleChildMenu.bind(this);
   }

   toggleChildMenu() {
      this.setState(state => ({
        open: !state.open
      }));
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
           <button onClick={this.toggleChildMenu}>
              Toggle Menu from Parent
           </button>
           <ChildComponent open={this.state.open} />
         </div>
       );
    }
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
         <Drawer open={this.props.open}/>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be used to control a css property like 'display'?  as in, if my prop 'open' contains either 'none' or 'inline-block', will the css display prop get updated?

Comment: I ended up using the react-classname package instead and used the 'display' prop as a boolean for whether or not to add a 'hidden' class to the element.  It was easier and my sr dev recommended it over my method.  thanks for the response though!

Comment: I don't know the react-classname package, one clean solution would be like this `className={this.props.open ? 'show' : 'hidden'}`

Comment: Yeah that is essentially what the react-classnames package does, but it also allows you to always apply a set of classnames, and conditionally apply others. Like this:     `classNames({ foo: true, bar: this.props.open });` // => 'foo' when this.props.open = false and 'foo bar' when this.props.open = true.

Comment: How can we change the open state in child component?

Comment: you can add a property `toggle` to the ChildComponent `<ChildComponent open={this.state.open} toggle={this.toggleChildMenu.bind(this)} />` and call `this.props.toggle()` in the child component

Comment: @OlivierBoissé How can we call this.props.toggle() in the child component?

Comment: I don't understand, you can call it wherever you want in the child component as soon as you specified this property when declaring the `ChildComponent` -> `<ChildComponent toggle={this.toggleChildMenu.bind(this)} />`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé what about the case where you have multiple child elements ? do you have to keep the state of each separately in the parent component?

Comment: @YasirJan you can declare an array into your state, each element in the array will match one child, you can use a `map` function in the `render` method to display the children

Comment: In this way, whole Parent component is being re-render by which we loose efficiency. Can you please tell any way in which only Child component will update its State or Props (means re-render) without re-render of Parent component.

Comment: looking for Hooks solution

Answer (score 35):

The parent component can manage child state passing a prop to child and the child convert this prop in state using componentWillReceiveProps.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  state = { drawerOpen: false }
  toggleChildMenu = () => {
    this.setState({ drawerOpen: !this.state.drawerOpen })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleChildMenu}>Toggle Menu from Parent</button>
        <ChildComponent drawerOpen={this.state.drawerOpen} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      open: false
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({ open: props.drawerOpen })
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <Drawer open={this.state.open} />
  }
}
```

Comment: in react 16 use getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam I'm using react version 16.7.0 with @Types/react version 16.7.18. At least on the TypeScript side there doesn't seem to be `getDerivedStateFromProps()`. However, Miguel's answer suggesting to use `componentWillReceiveProps(props)` is available and worked like a charm in my env.

Comment: In this case, how would the toggleMenu() state change inside the child component would reach the parent? Imagine I close the drawer, how would the parent component know it's been closed?

Answer (score 30):

You can use the `createRef` to change the state of the child component from the parent component. Here are all the steps.

1. Create a method to change the state in the child component.
2. Create a reference for the child component in parent component using `React.createRef()`.
3. Attach reference with the child component using `ref={}`.
4. Call the child component method using `this.yor-reference.current.method`.

**Parent component**

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
constructor()
{
this.changeChild=React.createRef()
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.changeChild.current.toggleMenu()}>
          Toggle Menu from Parent
        </button>
        <ChildComponent ref={this.changeChild} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false;
    }
  }

  toggleMenu=() => {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer open={this.state.open}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer I have found, because it does not re-render the parent component. This is much faster and much better practice!

Comment: Yes this is actually the best answer too for my needs. That's very clean, we should upvote this answer.

Comment: On parent, I had to use a handler method instead of directly calling the child. Then it worked.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for functional components. what would the equivalent implementation look like for a functional child component?

Answer (score 27):

Above answer is partially correct for me, but In my scenario, I want to set the value to a state, because I have used the value to show/toggle a modal. So I have used like below. Hope it will help someone.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible:false
  };

  handleCancel = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({ visible: false });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRef(this)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.onRef(undefined)
  }

  method() {
    this.setState({ visible: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (<Modal title="My title?" visible={this.state.visible} onCancel={this.handleCancel}>
      {"Content"}
    </Modal>)
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => {
    this.child.method() // do stuff
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child onRef={ref => (this.child = ref)} />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Child.method()</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Reference - https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/909#issuecomment-252969542

Comment: This is what I want, but I am wondering why not just use react refs? see[doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: What does the onRef prop do?

Comment: This is actually a discouraged pattern in react because it reverses information flow. If react has a single zen, it's _data down, actions up_. This is the concept that makes react apps so easy to reason about. Imperative handles can be useful but should be used sparingly and well-thought. They should not be the go-to solution for e.g. toggling visibility.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using functional components. You can achieve this by:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
   const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

   toggleChildMenu() {
      setIsOpen(prevValue => !prevValue)
   }

   return (
     <div>
       <button onClick={toggleChildMenu}>
         Toggle Menu from Parent
       </button>
       <Child open={isOpen} />
     </div>
   );
}



const Child = ({open}) => {
  return (
    <Drawer open={open}/>
  );
}
```

Comment: How can the child in this case control `open`? If the child say has a button to close the drawer, how does this work out?

Comment: We have to pass the `toggleChildMenu()` down to the child and trigger from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a prop from the parent and use it in child component so you will base child's state changes on the sent prop changes and you can handle this by using **getDerivedStateFromProps** in the child component.

Answer (score 0):

Here's in TypeScript and using function components, hope it helps

/* Child.tsx */

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

type Props = {
   onRef: (callback: Function) => void;
 }

export const Child: React.FC<Props> ({onRef}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    onRef(() => {
      console.log("Dude, see? It's working!");
    });
  }, [onRef]);
  
  return <h1 className={s.root}>Hello World!</h1>;
};
```

/* Parent.tsx */

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

export const Parent = () => {
  const callbackRef = useRef<Function>();
  const handleOnRef = (callback: Function) => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Child onRef={handleOnRef} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          callbackRef?.current?.();
        }}
      >
        Child.method()
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's another way that I tried yesterday

In your child script, define the method available to the parent and a regular component

```
    var ChildStateModificationFunc;
    const Child = ()=>{
    const [someState, setSomeState] = useState();

    //define the state that you want to modify
    ChildStateModificationFunc = (modVal)=>{
        setSomeState(modVal)
    }

    return (
    <div>
        {/* your child jsx here */}
    </div>
    }

    //export both the child and the method
    export default Child;
    export {ChildStateModificationFunc}
```

In your parent script, import both items

```
    import Child, {ChildStatteModificationFunc} from 'Child.js'

    const Parent = ()=>{

    var newVal = 'some parent val'  //let say you just fetch this from some web api
    //share the newVal with Child component
    ChildStatteModificationFunc(newVal)

    return(
    <div>
        <Child />
    </div>)
```