# How do I update the state of a react controlled component from it's parent?

Tags: reactjs

Given a react **controlled component** like the following from the react docs:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

What is the right way to change NameForm's `state.value` from NameForm's parent component?  In my specific use case, the user can type in the text input or the user can click some buttons in the parent that are meant to change the value of the input in the child component.

Edit: I should add that I m new to react so I may be overlooking the obvious.

Comment: See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041710/react-js-change-child-components-state-from-parent-component/39041951

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React js change child component's state from parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041710/react-js-change-child-components-state-from-parent-component)